# having error when represent data to the platform

Tags: java, groovy, iot

I get this error:

```
Message: exception 
Details: 'Cannot get property \'data\' on null object
```

Here’s my code:

```groovy
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import com.carriots.sdk.utils.BasicHttp;

def APIKEY = '1c7021dfcc02e4f52a8db39'

//// Data Fetching ////
def inc_data = context.data.data;
def d1 = inc_data[0..1];

//// Custom Rules declaration ////
def device_id = context.data.id;
def devicename = device_id + '23A2B@User.User';
def rssi = context.data.rssi;
def avgSnr = context.data.avgSnr;

def D1 = Long.parseLong(d1, 16)

//// Filter Status ////
if (D1 >= 1) {
    fltstatus = "motion detected";
} else {
    fltstatus = "No motion";
}

//// Payload ////
// Build Stream to persist.
// I think the error from the data variable but I do not why...
def data = '{"motion detection": "' + fltstatus + '"}'
def payload_data = '{"at": "now", "protocol": "v2", "device": "' + 
  devicename + '", "data": "' + data +'"}'

def basicHttp = new BasicHttp();
basicHttp.verb = "POST";
basicHttp.payload = payload_data;
basicHttp.url = "http://api.m.om/status/";
basicHttp.headers = [
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Listener-Carriots",
    "carriots.apikey": APIKEY
]
basicHttp.send();
```

Comment: What language is this? I don’t remember Java having a `def` keyword...

Comment: it is Groovy language

Answer (score 0):

Your first use of `data` as a property is this line:

```groovy
def inc_data = context.data.data;
                       ^    ^
                      (1)  (2)
```

Since you use it twice, it’s impossible to know which use is throwing the exception. I recommend breakpointing this line, then using your debugger to determine that:

- `context` is not null
- `context.data` is not null

Comment: when using only  def inc_data = context.data; i got this error 'Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object'

Comment: @fatma Then you have your answer: `context.data` is null. You should now go back to the part of your code where this parameter is set and determine why it was made null.